# Is sodium aquo complex a Brönsted-Lowry acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

I know that according to Brönsted-Lowry theory, a base is a proton acceptor while an acid is a proton donor. Also, the acid-base pair that differs by a single proton is a conjugate pair.

If this is true, then the sodium ion is a conjugate acid of sodium hydroxide. But if we look at $\ce{Na^+}$ itself, we find that it cannot donate a proton. Someone in the comments under [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/102195/95058) suggested that in its hydrated state, $\ce{Na^+}$ can act as a Brönsted-Lowry acid. How?

Comment: Not a duplicate of [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/101754/95058) which is the one about which I seek clarification.

Comment: " sodium ion is a conjugate acid of sodium hydroxide" - it is not. Protonate NaOH molecule and you'll find it.

Comment: @Mithoron I think I get it. As I understand it, and as someone else wrote on this SE, writing NaOH (aq) is really writing Na+ (aq) + OH- (aq). Protonating OH- gives H20, which is the conjugate acid, not Na+. In sum, is sodium ion not a Brönsted-Lowry acid?

Comment: It is an aqua complex and has been so for quite a while now.